# Fragment which autorefresh when something is edited

Tags: android, fragment, edit, profile

I don't know what I'm looking for that's why I'm posting here, I need something that would refresh or edit when I'm making some changes in other fragments. This is screenshot for describing what I need 
[image]

Sorry for the look, but that's all I've found and it is what I'm looking for.

So this is someone Profile hidden under white marker and when you push button to edit, you will see new Fragment which you could customize, add a photo, fill Name age etc... When you hit button Save you back to this frozen fragment and see updated information about your profile, but still, you can edit it again, as you can see.

I need some documentation solve this problem to understand that

Comment: You can achieve this by using 2 way 1) Using interface and 2) Using BroadcastReceiver

Comment: use localbroadcastmanager or eventbus

Comment: And how to customize switch like this one ? is there any posibilities ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this
Add This code in your Activity/Fragment

```
private BroadcastReceiver mMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
          // write your update code here
        }
    };
```

Register broadcast receiver in onCreate() if activity or onCreateView() if fragment

```
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(mActivity).registerReceiver(mMessageReceiver,
                new IntentFilter(Constant.UPDATE_CHAT_COUNT));
```

Un Register broadcast receiver in onDestroy() if activity or onDestroyView() if fragment

```
LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(mActivity).unregisterReceiver(mMessageReceiver);
```

After Updated profile notify using this code

```
 Intent intent1 = new Intent(Constant.UPDATE_CHAT_COUNT);             
 LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(mActivity).sendBroadcast(intent1);
```

Comment: Thx i will check it :)

Comment: Last one question, this box in xml should be as <fragment /> or someting else ?

Comment: @Kertuj It,s Depends on your requirement fragment or activity